# high voltage gem routing with locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, high-voltage

I am using `highvoltage gem` for static page serving. Its working but the url is ugly. Currently the `url` is like bellow:

> localhost:3000/pages/terms-and-conditions?locale=en

But i want the url to be like bellow:

> localhost:3000/en/pages/terms-and-conditions

In my routes file i wrote

```
scope ":locale", locale: /en|bn|hi/ do
  match "pages/:id" => 'pages#show', :as => :page, :format => false
end
```

then in view i wrote:

```
<%=link_to "Terms & Conditions", page_path(:id=>'terms-and-conditions')%>
```

in pages controller i wrote

```
  def show
    render params[:id]
  end
```

what can i do now to solve this problem

Comment: I have opened an issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/144

Answer (score 1):

I updated the issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/144

Here are the the instructions I posted on GitHub issues:

#### Add a before filter to your Application controller

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

#### Disable the default High Voltage routes

```
# config/initializers/high_voltage.rb
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.routes = false
end
```

#### Set up nested URLs with locales the routes file

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale", locale: /en|bn|hi/ do
  get "/pages/:id" => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :page, :format => false
end
```

#### Add a page to the site

```
# app/views/pages/about.html.erb
<%= t 'hello' %>
```

#### Make sure that there are corresponding locale files

```
/config/locale/en.yml
/config/locale/bn.yml
```

One last note is there is a [know issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/59) with High Voltage.

You'll need to specify routes like this `<%= link_to 'About Us', page_path(id: 'about') %>`

Let me know if you're still having issues with this and I can add some more details.